# Check the status of Windows Service via vSphere PowerCLI

Tags: powershell, powercli

Is there a way to reach a Windows VM Services from PowerCLI and do tasks like start/stop?

Like below which gets Disk Space information:

```
(((get-vm odcafc001gs1).ExtensionData).guest).Disk
```

Comment: Have you done any of your own research on this? Service management with PowerShell is quite simple and there are many questions on this on SO already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stop or start a service on remote machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43417672/stop-or-start-a-service-on-remote-machine)

Comment: Service management through powershell is quite simple (get-service, start-service, stop service)
but this will require server names as input.
but my intention is script will connect vcenter and for all vms, check the status of few important services .
I already have one script which is doing disk space check same way

Comment: You can use the servers IP instead of server name with all three of those cmdlets, I don't know vCenter but I would assume there is a way of getting that and then piping it to those Service cmdlets.

Comment: I don't use vCenter so can't test this but `(Get-VM -Name odcafc001gs1).Guest.IPAddress | Get-Service -Name spooler -ComputerName $_` looks like it should do what you want.