# How to set service startup mode to manual or automatic for a variety of servers?

Tags: powershell, service

First, I want to stop the services and then turn them on manually

```
$getservicestatus = (Get-Service -DisplayName $servicename -ComputerName $server).status

if ($getservicestatus -eq "Running") {
    Set-Service -Name $servicename -ComputerName $server -Status Stopped            
else
{
    Write-Host "$server $servicename var redan Running!" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Stop-Service spooler
    Set-Service spooler Manual
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The code fragment you have shown does not allow to reproduce your problem. Please read [mcve] and enhance your question. Clearly point out where you are stuck and which part of your code isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is [`Set-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-service) does not have a `ComputerName` parameter so it cannot act against remote services.

`Get-Service` can act against a remote computer (it does have the `ComputerName` parameter), this command returns a service object that can be piped to [`Set-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-service) to act remotely.

Assuming you want to Stop a remote service and set it to Manual startup, this would be the code:

```
$servicename = 'spooler'
$server = 'server2'

$service = Get-Service -Name $servicename -ComputerName $server

if ($service.Status -eq 'Running') {
    $service | Set-Service -Status Stopped
}

if ($service.StartType -eq 'Automatic') {
    $service | Set-Service -StartupType Manual
}

# If you need to start the service again
# $service | Set-Service -Status Running
```

Comment: _service object that can be piped to_.... Doesnt that just affect the service on the location machine though? I don't think piping it cares about the computer name and just end up doing local changes.

Comment: Yes it's only `Set-Service` that works remotely, `Start/Stop-Service` do not. Updated answer to reflect.

Comment: you might need to fix https://stackoverflow.com/a/43419192/3829407 as well

Comment: Simply select that property: `$service | Select-Object -ExpandProperty StartType`

Comment: is the correct? `if ($Getservice.startType -eq 'Automatic') {
    $service | Set-Service -StartType Manual`

Comment: Maybe, depends what `$Getservice` is.

Comment: oh, i I wrote wrong $service!
I want to do so to first check the status if it is automatic change it to manual otherwise write that it is already manually!

Comment: Then yes... it would be the same as the existing `if` but with the property and value changed accordingly. See edit.

Comment: How kan i have server name and service name and startuptype ? for example : aserver2 spooler automatic

Comment: A function would be best, see the documentation [about_functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions)

Comment: `function kollastatus() {

    $service = (Get-Service -DisplayName $servicename -ComputerName $server).status
    $service1= Select-Object -ExpandProperty StartType
    }
    
    if ($service1.StartType -eq 'manual'){
    kollastatus`

Comment: I'm not going to debug your code in comments. You need to go back to basics and learn powershell properly. That code is not valid and will not work... it's not even close to being correct and isn't a valid function.

Comment: "Set-Service does not have a `ComputerName` parameter" Depends on. The `Set-Service` cmdlet in the PowerShell version we are working with (5.1) does actually have a `ComputerName` parameter, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-service?view=powershell-5.1. I don't know why / if it has been removed in version 6, or it is simply a documentation issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this: change

```
Set-Service -Name $servicename -ComputerName $server -Status Stopped
```

to

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {Stop-Service -Name $servicename -Force}
```

Comment: how Can i write set-service command? I have problem there. And 
There are two or three different services in different servers